# facebook php sdk feed post max users

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a facebook app using the php sdk.
I'm storing the users information in a database to send them periodic notifications using feed post. How many users can I post to their walls in a time, as the post is the same, but it has to be sent to many users?
Is it allowed to send bulk feed posts? I'M NOT SPAMMING OF COURSE. It's related to the application itself.

I have an array of user id's which has 1219 user id's.
Should I split it to arrays of 100 or even 10 users and send one array per hour for example, or there is no problem to send them all together?

And if there is no problem legally, how to do it technically?

```
$attachment = array(.........);

$users = array(.......);

foreach..... {
    $facebook->api('/' . $userid . '/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
}
```

is this the best way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can u do the posting in a loop, and just in case the user has reached the limit, facebook will return that as an error.  So, try to catch for the error and stop the publishing.

Answer (score 0):

For today users: You can use [Facebook BATCH API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/) to make multiple Graph API requests in one call (you can also use different access token for every request).